# How do a I mock a list of Async tasks to unit test a function

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await, task, moq

I have a function which takes a list of `Task<T>` and returns an `int` indicating how many of those tasks are running at a given time.

```
 public int GetActiveTasks(List<Task<SomeClass>> tasks)
        {
            return tasks.Count(x=>
                x.Status == TaskStatus.Created ||
                x.Status == TaskStatus.Running ||
                x.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation ||
                x.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingToRun ||
                x.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingForChildrenToComplete);
        }
```

Now the issue is that I want to write some unit tests around this but the Status property on the task doesnt have a setter (which makes sense - why would it?)

So my plan had been to create a list of tasks like this :

```
var taskList = new List<Task<SomeClass>>()
            {
                new Task<SomeClass>() { Status = TaskStatus.Running },
                new Task<SomeClass>() { Status = TaskStatus.Cancelled },
            };
```

and then pass that into the function and check that the integer output was what I expected.

But because I cant explicitly set the status I'm a bit stuck.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Task.FromResults`, `Task.FromException`, `Task.FromCancelled`, `Task.Delay()` and why do you need to check the `Waiting` statuses?

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` probably returns a task waiting for children to complete

Comment: Its a long story, but we have a business requirement to send a bunch of data to a 3rd party api but it cant handle more than x requests at a time (say 5). So we need to send 100 requests in batches of 5. We can either send 5 and use whenall() before sending more which is inefficient as some might take 20ms to complete and some might take 20000ms... so instead we keep a track of how many tasks we have and what their status is, we send 5 requests off to the api and as each task comes back we send another request off, so while we have work queued we will always have 5 tasks in progress.

Comment: Thats the best explanation I can give for a fairly complicated business process given the character constraints...

Comment: You don't need to check task statuses then, you need eg an `ActionBlock<T>` with a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` set to 5. Eg `var block=new ActionBlock<T>(t=>someAction(t),new ExecutionDataFlowBlockOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism=5}); foreach(var msg in messages){ block.Post(msg);} block.Complete(); await block.Completion;`

Comment: Check [How to: Specify the Degree of Parallelism in a Dataflow Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-specify-the-degree-of-parallelism-in-a-dataflow-block).

Comment: I use blocks to request the status of several thousand air tickets every day, from a rather flaky API that can't handle more than 4 concurrent requests without crashing for 1 minute. The responses need to be parsed and inserted into a database. Each of these steps is a dataflow block with its own degree of parallelism. The blocks form a pipeline so I can start by posting eg ticket numbers to the head block and await for the bulk import block at the end to finish once all tickets have been requested, parsed and inserted

Comment: That looks like it might be a good replacement, for the task management code that we have, Ill knock up a proof of concept and give it a try, Thanks :)

Comment: Your process sounds very similar to ours (apart from the airline tickets) - Ill definitely try to get this implemented tonight :)

Comment: This process is quite similar to Go's channels and goroutines. .NET has this since 2012. If you can think of a way to structure your process as a pipeline (think SSIS's dataflow pipelines), you can implement it using the Dataflow library

Comment: Ive been a .net developer since 2003 but because I was working on old systems I've only recently started to get exposure to Async and Await.

Am I understanding that WorkerBlock correctly, if I have 1000 items I want to be processed no more than 5 at a time I just create a workerblock and pass all 1000 items to it and it will manage them for me until they are all complete?

Comment: Yes. The default is one at a time. Parallelism comes from executing each block in the pipeline on its own thread. Nothing prevents you from increasing the DOP to what you want though

Comment: Thanks, I've replaced our code with an action block now and started the tests running - if it works as Ive understood it its going to save a tonne of time for me writing new tests, Thanks! :)